# Apache rewrite to www. unless it is a dev domain

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my current rewrite code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

I would like to add a line that stops the `www.` forward if the `HTTP_HOST` is  the `dev` domain for the site.

- Fake Dev Example:  `food.example.dev`
- Fake Production Example: `food.example`
- Currently the dev domain would redirect to `www.food.example.dev`
- `food.example` should forward to `www.food.example`
- but `food.example.dev` shouldn't forward to `www.food.example.dev`

What would be a good way to handle this?  I have tried a couple different scenarios. I think adding the `http` to `https` in there as well might be complicating things because of the `[OR]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think adding the http to https in there as well might be complicating things

Yes, the above (generic) directives are *both* non-www to www *and* HTTP to HTTPS. With the way these directives are written you can't have one without the other.

To exclude your dev domain from these directives - which will remove the www *and* HTTPS redirect from your dev domain then you can simply add an exception (an additional `RewriteCond` directive) to the top. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^food\.example\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

If the requested host does not start with `food.example.dev` (your dev domain) then proceed as normal.

However, if you want to still redirect your dev domain to HTTPS, but not www, then you'll need to split your current rule into two.

For example:

```
# 1. www to non-www (excluding dev domain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^food\.example\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# 2. HTTP to HTTPS (all domains)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This maintains at most a single redirect. However, if you plan to implement HSTS then you'll need to reverse these two rules and redirect to HTTPS first and potentially get at most two redirects.

You could exclude all requests to your dev domain (ie. all subdomains) by changing the *CondPattern* to `!\.example\.dev`. ie. Does not *contain* `.example.dev`.

NB: You should first test with 302 (temporary) redirects - to avoid caching issues, and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the *erroneous* redirects to www on the dev domain are likely to have been cached by the browser.

Comment: I've never redirected capitalized domains before.  I don't think you should.  Domains are case insensitive.  Redirecting is being sensitive about case.   My browsers lowercase domains before they are sent to the server.  Googlebot lowercases domains before fetching.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Admittedly, a non-lowercase domain name in the request is very much an edge case - possibly an obscure "bot" or devious request (that may not even follow redirects anyway). "Domains are case insensitive." - but with mod_rewrite we are comparing it in a case-sensitive manner, unless we use the `NC` flag. If we don't redirect the request then we potentially allow the "bot" access to the content via a non-canonical URL, which may be less desirable. If the "bot" does not follow redirects then it gets just a minimal response and we minimise wasting server resources.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Another option might be to simply block such requests (where the `Host` header is not all lowercase)? _Aside:_ A bit of an issue with using "generic" directives (as used here) that don't explicitly include the hostname in the _substitution_ string is that we are not actually canonicalising the hostname to all lowercase in the redirect.

Comment: Although, in this case, the use of the `NC` on the dev domain is to _prevent_ a redirect. (But the dev domain is probably not publicly accessible anyway, so it probably makes no difference at all in this case.) AH, actually, there should be an `NC` flag on the rule that checks against `!^www\.` - otherwise there is potential for a malformed redirect! eg. `www.WWW.example.com`. Again, extreme edge case, but hey... ho hum, I'll update my answer!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the query - made me think more about it, and helped me spot that error!